# What is a purpuse of creating default admin user for organization by cryptogen tool?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to understand why hyperledger cryptogen tool creates admin user by default for organiztion, because, when I am using sdk, I have to create p/k for user and make enroll request to organization's ca, and it gives me signed cert for user or admin and with this user I can invoke some transactions or make peer to join channel (if this user is admin) or etc. So for what reason should I use default admin user, what is a purpose of default admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no admin, then who will register and enroll users? If you are able to enroll users without default admin generated by cryptogen, then go for it! You don't need default admin in that case.

Also note that cryptogen should not be used in production. From official [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/commands/cryptogen.html):

> It would normally not be used in the operation of a production
>   network.

Adding some more details as to why cryptogen would not be used in production. As I understand, Its not that the tool lacks some functionality. But it wouldn't be used in production because:

1. Copying the secrets over to a remote server is less than ideal. This can be prevented by running cryptogen on the server. So there is a solution around this problem.
2. The real reason why cryptogen would not be used in production is because how would one dynamically register and enroll users? Cryptogen can be used to register a known set of users prior to launching the network, but think about how you would sign up new users? For that you need [fabric-ca](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html).